# Spark Streaming not honoring auto.offset.reset="smallest" or group.id?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm creating a Kafka stream in Spark 1.6:

```
kafkaProps.setConfig("group.id", UUID.randomUUID().toString())

kafkaProps.createConfiguration()
kafkaProps.toImmutableMap.foreach {keyVal => println(keyVal._1 + "=" + keyVal._2)}

val ssc = new StreamingContext( sc, Seconds(2) ) 
val stream = ssc.createKafkaStream[String, String,  StringDeserializer, StringDeserializer](
                     kafkaProps,
                     List(kafkaProps.getConfig("kafka.topic"))
                     )
stream.print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(30000)
ssc.stop(stopSparkContext=false, stopGracefully=true)
```

The kafkaProps contains:

```
...
group.id=3abedbf7-2aed-436a-b4bc-0517a9c5c419
...
auto.offset.reset=smallest
...
```

The *group.id* changes it's value every time I run the code as desired. I thought this was enough to reset the offset to zero each time I run my application when consuming from Kafka, but the old items in the topic are not retrieved.

Any ideas?

Comment: What type is `kafkaProps`?

Comment: I was expecting to find it to be a map but it doesn't seem to be https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-messgehub-spark-samples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/ibm/cds/spark/samples/config/MessageHubConfig.scala though spark maybe calling a method that returns it as a map https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-messgehub-spark-samples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/ibm/cds/spark/samples/config/DemoConfig.scala#L89

Comment: If you invoke that implicit yourself on the config object, do you see your properties there properly set?

Comment: Yeah, I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems years have passed since this topic was raised. However, I would like to answer for other people who will be googling for it.

The answer is that streaming-kafka-010 ignores "auto.offset.reset" and simply put it to "none" if it was not.

You could find this piece of code in method fixKafkaParams of org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtil.

```
logWarning(s"overriding ${ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG} to none for executor")
kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "none")
```

There is further explaining on the override in org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD where the value of "auto.offset.rest" is rechecked.

```
require("none" ==    kafkaParams.get(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG).asInstanceOf[String],
ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG +
  " must be set to none for executor kafka params, else messages may not match offsetRange")
```

In general, "auto.offset.reset" is not supported in KafkaStreaming

Comment: any idea on how to start from latest offset in case of restarts due to outof offset exception

Answer (score 0):

have you tried 'earliest' rather than 'smallest' as a value ?

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#configuration

[latest, earliest, none] are the values for the new consumer

[smallest,largest] are the values for the old consumer

Comment: Yep.  Unfortunately this didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the definition of method `StreamingContext#createKafkaStream`.  Could you clarify where have you found it?

Try to create Kafka stream using `KafkaUtils` as referred in [Spark official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/streaming-kafka-integration.html)

```scala
val directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[
     [key class], [value class], [key decoder class], [value decoder class] ](
     streamingContext, [map of Kafka parameters], [set of topics to consume])
```